# Sending files to users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, pdf, c#-4.0

Anyone have any quick ways to send a file to a user? I can generate pdfs on the fly but need a way of passing it to the client then deleting the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

try the [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) - Response - well one of it's derived classes of course.
You can often just write return File(...) (see [Controller.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx)) and also look at [ASP.NET MVC ploading and Downloading Files](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files) for some further examples and working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can `return File(stream, contentType)` or `return File(filename, contentType)` to send the file to the user. If you can generate the PDF straight to a stream and avoid creating a file on disk then you're done. If it has to be created on disk then you should be able to delete the file in `OnResultExecuted`.

Comment: if on disk I would copy it into a MemoryStream and delete before returning - seems cleaner than spliting the action into do/cleanup part.

Comment: The problem with copying it into a MemoryStream is that you then have to have the whole file in memory before sending it to the user. Whether that's a problem depends on how large the files are and how many simultaneous requests you've got to deal with.

Comment: yep - you're right on this - but a PDF might not be as big ... on the other hand if it's a book ... well sorry you ARE right